# Automator - Crop From Specified Edge

Tags: macos, mac, batch, automator, crop

I'm trying to create an Automator folder action to automatically crop images that are added to a specific folder. It works; however, it crops the images towards the center. How can I crop starting from the right edge? I found [Propper Cropper](http://automatorworld.com/archives/propper-cropper/), which looks like it does what I need, but unfortunately it was compiled for PPC, and is therefore not a universal action. Is there an alternative (preferably an Automator action)? If this is not possible with Automator, is there some other software I can download to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then install ImageMagick with `brew install imagemagick`.

[image]

```
for f in "$@"; do
    # mogrify when file is a png or file is a jpg image
    [[ "$f" != *.png && "$f" != *.jpg ]] && continue
    /usr/local/bin/mogrify -crop 50x50+0+0 "$f"
done
```

- `-crop 50x50+0+0`: crop from the top left corner, create only one image
- `-crop 50x50+0+0 -gravity SouthEast`: crop from the bottom right corner
- `-resize 160x90^ -gravity center -extent 160x90`: make images smaller or bigger and crop them so that they fill the specified area
- `-crop '-50-50' -crop '+50+50'`: crop 50 pixels from all sides

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/ for more examples.